# Multimodal routing with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I try to develop a multimodal routing system, based on data in a Neo4j Database.
My idea was the following:

### Nodes

Stop:
A node that represents a bus stop, railway stop, ride share offers, car rent or car sharing station etc.

Schedule:
A schedule for service times of this stop.
In the case of public transport, it includes the departure times for the weekdays. In the case of car rent, it includes e.g. the opening hours. For ride share it includes the date and the time of departure.

Offer:
The corresponding mobility offer for this stop. If the current stop belongs to public transport, this is just a marker for the service line and some other information. In the case of ride share, it includes additional information about this.

### Edges

connected_by:
Nodes are connected through this edge, if it is the same transportation mode (no changes on stops etc.)
Attributes are: distance, travel time, price

switch_to (could also be called connected_by, but has different attributes):
Nodes are connected through this edge, if it is a different transportation mode (changes on stops are required)
Attributes are: switch time

scheduled_by:
Nodes and Schedules are connected through this edge.

offered_by:
Schedules and Offers are connected by this edge.

If a user asks for a connection from Point A to Point B, how can I calculate this?
My first idea was something like that:

```
MATCH (from {name: 'test'}),(to {name: 'test3'}), p = (from)-[:connected_by*]-(to)
RETURN p AS shortestPath, reduce(cost=0, rel in relationships(p) | cost + rel.cost) AS totalCost
ORDER BY totalCost ASC
```

But what I really want to get is:

All nodes on the way from Point A to point B, the corresponding offers, the total price, the required switches (to change the transportation mode) and the total traveling time. Particularly the traveling time is difficult because one has to consider:

- the travel time in "connected_by"
- the switch time in "switch_to"
- the waiting time: e. g. I am at Node1 at 11:07 and the next departure is at 11:15, then I have to wait 8 minutes.
- if the journey goes from 11 pm to 1 am one has to ensure, that the calculation is correct.

Furthermore, the price is difficult because it can be a price for one connection (ride share, railway), a time depending price (car sharing, per hour/day) or a ticket of public transport (valid for multiple connections but just for certain time period and a certain area).

Is there a way to achieve this by a cypher statement? Maybe if I simplify the data structure (the information must be the same)? If not, what is the best way to get this information (Java Program?).

EDIT 1:
Here is the actual model of the graph:
[image: Graph Model]

Here is an example:

[image: Example Graph]

In the example, you can see the calculation for one person, traveling from Point A to the Destination. Therefore the person has to walk by foot, takes the bus and uses a ride share offer.

Comment: I think to get better traction on this question, and help people understand your problem, it might be worth adding a diagram (or better yet creating a graph gist - http://portal.graphgist.org/about).

Comment: Ok, I added the model and an example. If there are still questions, please let me know and I will add the required information.